# ファイルやフォルダの所有者・アクセス許可を自動で変更したい

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10(x64)環境で、特定のフォルダツリー（たとえば、c:\sbin\ にシステム管理用の自作スクリプト各種を保管しているとします）を次のような設定に変更する作業を自動化したいと考えています。

(1) c:\sbin\ 配下の全てのファイル・フォルダの所有者を、Builtin\Administrators に変更する。また、管理者権限に昇格しない限りファイルの追加・削除・改変ができないようにする。

(2) ただし、c:\sbin\#Incoming とその配下に限り、Everyone に対してフルコントロールを出す。その際同時に、誰か一般ユーザーがその中に投入していたファイル・フォルダもすべて「Everyone に対してフルコントロール」に変更する。
（c:\sbin\#Incoming フォルダ自体の移動・削除・改名は禁止。）

今は不定期で手作業で処理しているのですが、手作業ではミスが発生しやすいのと、実は c:\sbin\ 以外にも同様の運用をしたいフォルダが複数あるので、もし自動化できるなら自動化したいと考えています。具体的なツール、コマンド、APIなどご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ぜひご教授いただければ幸いです。

【当方が使用可能な言語】
●C言語(MinGW-w64、32bit/64bit両方の環境あり)
●ActivePerl
●WSH
●バッチファイル(cmd.exe)
※PowerShellはほぼチンプンカンプンです。
※C#や.Net系の開発環境はありません。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 手動で処理しているということですが、その場合の実行するコマンドなどを教えて下さい。

Comment: 頑張ってPowerShellを勉強するのが良いんじゃないですか？ こんな記事が参考になりそうです。[How to change file permissions on Windows via powershell / cmd?](https://superuser.com/q/1539172), [Set folder permissions through CMD - MS Windows](https://superuser.com/q/1789769), [PowerShell Setting advanced NTFS permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26543127/9014308), [How to grant directory permissions in a Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63671763/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。今のところ、すべてGUIで操作しています。
（c:\sbin\ のプロパティを開いて、「セキュリティ」タブを開いて… です。）

ご紹介いただいた過去記事には、PowerShellを使う方法以外にも cacls.exe　/　icacls.exe と takeown.exe が紹介されていました。まずはその方法で、いろいろ試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0):

以下の内容を .bat ファイルにして、管理権限で実行することで対応できないでしょうか？
(*) 必ず対象フォルダー以下のバックアップを取得してからテスト実行してください。

```
@echo off

set targetFolderForAdmin=C:\sbin
set targetFolderForAll=C:\sbin\#Incoming

rem 対象フォルダのアクセス権の継承を無効化
icacls %targetFolderForAdmin% /inheritance:r

rem 対象フォルダ以下の所有者を BUILTIN\Administorators へ変更
takeown /F %targetFolderForAdmin% /R /A

rem 対象フォルダ以下のフルアクセスを BUILTIN\Administorators のみに設定
icacls %targetFolderForAdmin% /grant:r BUILTIN\Administrators:F /T /C /Q

rem 対象フォルダ以下のフルアクセスを Everyone に設定
icacls %targetFolderForAll% /grant Everyone:F /T /C /Q
```

もし、目的と異なる場合は、GUI で行っている手順を共有いただくことで、より厳密な再現方法をお伝えできるかもしれません。

Comment: わざわざありがとうございます。まさにこのバッチファイル通りのことを考えていました。これをベースにして、いろいろ試してみようと思います。